# TYPO3 Fluid use iterator for second array

Tags: arrays, loops, content-management-system, iteration, typo3

I am currently developing a TYPO3 extension where I work with two separate arrays: one contains the text information about products (*bikes*), the second contains the corresponding images (*bikesimages*). In the frontend template, I iterate through the products with a for loop.

My question: how can I use the iterator of the for loop (*bikeIterator*) to access the same index of the second array?

```
<f:for each="{bikes}" as="bike" iteration="bikeIterator">               
    <div class="teaser-image"><f:image src="{bikesimages.{bikeIterator}}" alt="{bike.manufacturer} {bike.type}" /></div>
```

This does not work. How do I use the iterator correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{bikeIterator}` is an object itself with several methods/properties you can use. I'll give you an example. Given you have 3 bikes the iterator gives you the following options:

1st Bike:

```
{bikeIterator.index} = 0
{bikeIterator.cycle} = 1
{bikeIterator.isFirst} = 1
{bikeIterator.isLast} = 0
{bikeIterator.isEven} = 0
{bikeIterator.isOdd} = 1
```

2nd Bike:

```
{bikeIterator.index} = 1
{bikeIterator.cycle} = 2
{bikeIterator.isFirst} = 0
{bikeIterator.isLast} = 0
{bikeIterator.isEven} = 1
{bikeIterator.isOdd} = 0
```

3rd Bike:

```
{bikeIterator.index} = 2
{bikeIterator.cycle} = 3
{bikeIterator.isFirst} = 0
{bikeIterator.isLast} = 1
{bikeIterator.isEven} = 0
{bikeIterator.isOdd} = 1
```

## TYPO3 >= 8LTS

Since TYPO3 8LTS fluid is capable of dynamic varible assignent. So you can go with this solution:

```
<f:for each="{bikes}" as="bike" iteration="bikeIterator">               
    <div class="teaser-image"><f:image src="{bikesimages.{bikeIterator.index}}" alt="{bike.manufacturer} {bike.type}" />
</div>
```

## TYPO3 <= 7LTS

Anyway in TYPO3 7LTS or lower you cant pass `{bikeIterator.index}` to `{bikesimages}` like you tried. I recommend to implement your own ViewHelper that takes the `{bikeIterator.index}` and the `{bikesimages}` objectStorage or array and returns the path for the image src.

So you can write afterwards in your template:

```
<f:image src="{myNamespace:myViewHelper(index:bikeIterator.index, bikesImgaes: bikesImages)}" alt="{bike.manufacturer} {bike.type}" />
```

In your ViewHelper you have something like this:

```
/**  
 * @param integer $index
 * @param array $bikesImages
 * @return string
 */ 
public function render($index, $bikesImages) {
    return $bikesImages[$index] ?: 'path/to/dummyImage.png';
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my problem. The call of the ViewHelper now looks like this: `<div class="teaser-image"><f:image src="{chiliUsedbikes:GetBikeTeaserImage(index: '{bikeIterator.index}', bikesimages: '{bikesimages}')}" alt="{bike.manufacturer} {bike.type}" /></div>`